Laravel dusk no test found if i rename the file
When I try to use dusk it works fine but if I rename the file from ExampleTest.php to something else it will return:

INFO NO Test Found

I tried to rename the test file and somehow it won't work. If I still use ExampleTest.php it works.

Test classes need to end with "Test", so if you rename to for example "MyFirsTestExample" it won't be recognized as a test.
